# Apply css styles in table created in Javascript (JQuery Mobile)

Tags: javascript, php, css, html-table

I have a table that is created dynamically using PHP and Javascript. Now, I'm trying to styling the last one `<tr>` to add a padding and border, but it doesn't work.

How can I proceed? I need call some element like trigger('create') or others?

Part of my code:

```
$.ajax ( {
        beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); }, //Show spinner
        complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() }, //Hide spinner
        url: "http://www.someweb.com/somePHP.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            for(var i = 0; i< data[1].length;i++){
                table += "<tr><td>"+data[1][i].mon_da+"</td>";
                table += "<td>"+Number(data[1][i].mon_qu).toFixed(2)+"€</td>";
                table += "<td>"+data[1][i].mon_con+"</td></tr>";
            }
            table += "<tr style='border:1px solid;padding-top:20px;'><td colspan='2'><b>Disp:</b></td><td><b>"+Number(data[0].usr_to).toFixed(2)+"€</b></td></tr>";
            document.getElementById("tableMo").innerHTML = table;
        }
    });
```

Comment: what *doesn't work* about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can't apply styles to `<tr>`s like that](http://jsfiddle.net/vmw28/).

You can [try applying them to the `<td>`s instead.](http://jsfiddle.net/vmw28/1/)

I would personally prefer to add a class to the `tr` and handle the styles externally to JS in a CSS file.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmw28/2/)

**HTML**

```
<tr class="stylish">
    <td colspan='2'><b>Disp:</b></td>
    <td><b>"+Number(data[0].usr_to).toFixed(2)+"€</b></td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
.stylish td {
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding-top:20px;
}
.stylish td:first-child {
    border-right:0;
}
.stylish td:last-child {
    border-left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's the best solution for my problem. It Works! ;D

Answer (score 0):

You can get the table element by id and then add CSS style property with javascript:

for example:

```
   document.getElementById("tableMo").style.border = "1px solid black";
document.getElementById("tableMo").style.padding = "10px";
```

Check out some DOM style tutorial, it might help you

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_style.asp

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to add a class to your `tr` tags like so:

```
table += "<tr class='rowStyle'><td>"+data[1][i].mon_da+"</td>";
```

now you can style the rows,
or if you want to style the table itself, you can use jquery to get the parent of the row like so:

```
var obj = $('.rowStyle').closest('table');
```

and just give it an ID:

```
$(obj).attr('id','tableID');
```

Now just style it.

Although this is a lengthy method of doing it.

*Hope this helps :)*

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using jquery css selector

Comment: $('tr:last-child').css('border','1px solid #000');